# javascript, loop array, pull the 1st item only once

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, for-loop

I have a a series of arrays I need to loop through and extract specific content.

here is an example of the arrays:

```
["Title", "Subline 1"]
["Title", "Subline 2"] 
["Title", "Subline 3"] 
["Title", "Subline 4"] 
["Title", "Subline 5"]
```

the title in each array will be the same but the subline is different.

I can loop thgouth this fine and pull either both elements or just the title or the subline.

But I would like to loop over the arrays pull the title of the first array then just the sub lines on the remaining arrays and this is where I get stuck, I have no idea to to structure a loop to do that.

The output should look like:

```
Title
Subline 1
Subline 2
Subline 3
Subline 4
Subline 5
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there, can you show us what you've tried so far?

Comment: Is this like group by Title?

Comment: I Have'nt tried anything for this yet, as i am really not sure how to structure it.

And yes I suppose it is like group by title

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you have an array of arrays named `arrays`

```
var result = [arrays[0][0]].concat(arrays.map(function(item){
  return item[1];
}));
```

Or if you want it to be "one loop"

```
var result = arrays.reduce(function(acc, x, i) {
    if(!i) acc.push(x[0])
    acc.push(x[1]);
    return acc;
}, []);
```

Comment: plus 1 for the map + concat combo, way better than for + push

Answer (score 2):

If you have multiple titles ...

```
var arr1 = ["Title 1", "Subline 1"];
var arr2 = ["Title 1", "Subline 2"];
var arr3 = ["Title 1", "Subline 3"];
var arr4 = ["Title 2", "Subline 1"];
var arr5 = ["Title 2", "Subline 2"];

var arrays = [arr1, arr2, arr3, arr4, arr5];

var result = arrays.reduce(function(result, item) {
    var arr = result[item[0]] = result[item[0]] || [];
    arr.push(item[1]);
    return result;
}, {});
```

demo output to console

```
Object.keys(result).forEach(function(key) {
    console.log(key);
    result[key].forEach(function(sub) {
        console.log('    ', sub);
    });
});
```

output:

```
Title 1
    Subline 1
    Subline 2
    Subline 3
Title 2
    Subline 1
    Subline 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a variable to control if the title was already pulled out.
Example:

```
var arr1 = ["Title", "Subtitle"];
var arr2 = ["Title", "Subtitle2"];
var arr3 = ["Title", "Subtitle3"];

var titlePulled = false;
var i = 0;

//1st for
for (i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    if (!titlePulled && i == 0) {
        titlePulled = true;
        console.log(arr1[i]);
    }
    else {
        console.log(arr1[i]);
    }
}

//2nd for
for (i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++) {
    if (!titlePulled && i == 0) {
        titlePulled = true;
        console.log(arr2[i]);
    }
    else {
        console.log(arr1[i]);
    }
}
```

And so on

Comment: Using `return` will exit the function immediately, ending the loop.

Comment: Excuse me, wanted to write console.log but was thinking of return. Editing in a minute.

Comment: This seems way more complicated than necessary. You have loops even though the arrays are always just 2 elements. And except for `arr1`, only the second element needs to be printed.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the title from the first element before the loop.

```
var array = [
    ["Title", "Subline 1"],
    ["Title", "Subline 2"],
    ["Title", "Subline 3"],
    ["Title", "Subline 4"],
    ["Title", "Subline 5"]
];

console.log(array[0][0]); // First title
for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    console.log(array[i][1]); // Every Subline
}
```